# data from facebook deeplink is always null

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, deeplink

Я запускаю рекламу компанию в facebook, и не могу получить deeplink, с помощью методов указанных в документации.

Только один из методов описанных в документации работает, но не один из них не работает как отложенный диплинк (через маркет)

Вот два метода, описанные в документации

```
AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this, new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
            if (appLinkData!=null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"appLinkData is "+appLinkData.getTargetUri().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"appLinkData is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });


    Uri targetUrl =
            AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl.equals(null)) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    }
```

Первый метод возвращает всегда null, второй метод возвращает линк только когда приложение уже установлено, но через play market его не передает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском. И код нужно вставить текстом, а не скриншотом.

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых случаях диплинк не будет приходить повторно на одно и тоже устройство, даже если переустанавливать приложение по новому и делать новые рекламные объявления, попробуйте в первую очередь использовать новое устройство.

Так же могу сказать что для отслеживания диплинка достаточно подключить Facebook SDK и добавить метод onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched, больше ничего, даже в манифесте не надо прописывать intent-filter с scheme.

Answer (score 0):

```
    AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(this,getString(R.string.facebook_app_id),
            new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                    // Process app link data

                    Log.d("TAG", "Deep link receive" + appLinkData);

                    Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrl(getIntent());
                    if (targetUrl != null) {


                        Log.d("TAG",   "oppppp" +  targetUrl.toString());
                        webView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String url2 = url + "?sub1=google";

                                webView.loadUrl(url2);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]